# Recommendations for turning multiple solutions/projects into a single msdeploy package?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, msdeploy, webdeploy

Our main website is a collection of 10 separate ASP.NET projects and applications. At the moment, to do a complete deployment onto a fresh server involves running ten separate msdeploy jobs; each application is built, configured (using config transforms) and packaged, but we don't have any solution for deploying all the packages as a single operation.

I can see several possibilities that *might* work in this scenario, but would love to hear from anybody who has succeeded - or failed - in setting up something similar:

1. A folder full of packages and deploy.cmd scripts, with a "master script" that will call each individual app script in turn and deploy that app to the target server.
2. Using a staging server where we deploy the latest build of each package from TeamCity using the production configuration, but then use msdeploy to capture that server into a single enormous msdeploy ZIP package, which is then deployed onto each production server as a single msdeploy step.
3. Creating a single, enormous Visual Studio solution that references EVERY project in our codebase (perhaps via svn:externals?), compiles and cross-references them ALL, and hence supports using a single msbuild job to create a huge monolithic package containing our entire codebase, built from the latest revision in source control and configured for the target environment.

I've studied [Troy Hunt's excellent "You're Deploying it Wrong" series](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html), and [Scott Hanselman's "Web Deployment Made Awesome"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx) article, but I think I'm looking for something a step beyond either of these approaches that incorporates multiple projects and applications without necessarily building them from source in a single step - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We had a very similar scenario in our company, and we created an installation package using [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/). Our config transform happens at installation time, so now we create a single build, then deploy that to each server via an MSI install package. WIX is very flexible, but also has a steep learning curve.  We modify our configs using our own custom action, but it could be done other ways.

We use Team Foundation Server and [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393574.aspx) to do our builds.  This is pretty straight forward, but did take some work to set up correctly with as many projects and solutions as we had.

Other options we looked into, and even tried were:

- InstallShield - Not flexible enough.
- Writing our own C# Install - WIX already thought of everything we
  were trying to accomplish so why reinvent the wheel?
- Just saying to heck with it all and installing things manually - 2 or
  3 months of development time in WIX and MSBuild have easily paid for
  the hours we would have spent of the last year doing things manually.

I think the deployment tools built into Visual Studio were designed for a single application with just a few deployments.  It sounds like you need external tools, and development effort, to get your deployments quicker, and eliminate the need for doing things manually.  That's why we invested in the above solution, and it has really paid off.

Answer (score -1):

I'll pick Installshield.

- Installshield latest versions support creating webdeploy packages.
- You can define the IIS configurations for all apps in a single project and create releases if you want to create packages by separate or one single release for all web apps.
- Installshield project has an object model where you can automate basically every task from build scripts, also the projects are simple xml files that you can also modify in automation scripts if required
- Developers can modify update WixXML projects by separate and you can add those projects builds as merge modules to your installshield projects through your build scripts with some little tweaks to the installshield project xml (at least in 2011 version, this part is not supported by installshield but can be done)
- You don't even need to modify Visual Studio Projects for groups of web apps that follow a same pattern, neither manually modify your installshield project to add new web apps for these cases, you can create packages for new web apps without intervention setting one time your build scripts for the installshield project automation task based on the root VS build output